# How to chain multiple API calls

Tags: angular, api, typescript

I have to chain 2 API calls, in my component I want to receive the data from the last call, or handle any errors.

Here's my component, which starts the initial API call.

**Component**

```
  public handleSubmit(){
    if(this.loginForm.valid) {
      this.authService.authenticate(this.authRequest)
      .subscribe(
        data => console.log(data),
        error => console.log(error)
      );
    }
  }
```

**Service**

My `authenticate` call can succeed or fail. If it fails, I want to throw an error, if it succeeds it should start the second call.

```
authenticate(request: models.AuthenticationRequest) {

    ...

    return this.httpClient.get(environment.auth.ssoAuthorize,
    { 
        headers: headers,
        params: params
    }).pipe(
        map((response: {code: string}) => {
            if(response.code){
                this.getAuthenticationToken(response.code).subscribe(
                    data => { return data }
                )
            }
        }),
        catchError(error => this.handleError(error))
    );
}
```

this is the final call, this call receives data that I have to send to my component.

```
getAuthenticationToken(code: string): Observable<any> { 

    ...

    return this.httpClient.post(environment.auth.token, {}, {
        headers: headers,
        params: params,
    }).pipe(
        map((response: models.AuthenticationTokenResponse) => {
            if(response.access_token){
                localStorage.setItem('authToken', JSON.stringify(response));
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }),
        catchError(error => this.handleError(error))
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To concatenate two Observables, one depending the other use switchMap. (if the observables are independents, you can use forkJoin.

SwitchMap is like:

```
return observable1.pipe(
      switchMap(res=>{
           //here we can use res
           console.log(res)
           //but we can not return res, we can return
           return observable2(res)
      });
```

In your case

```
authenticate()
{
    return this.httpClient.get(environment.auth.ssoAuthorize,
    { 
        headers: headers,
        params: params
    }).pipe(
        switchMap((response: {code: string}) => {
            //we not want return response, we can return:
            if(response.code){
                return this.getAuthenticationToken(response.code)
            }
            else   //we must return an observable
            {
                return Observable.of(false);
            }
        }),
        catchError(error => this.handleError(error))
    );
```